# Non decreasing real function satisfying $f(x)=f(x+1)$ and/or $f(x)=f(x-1)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, contest-math

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a non-decreasing function. For all $x\in\mathbb R$ we have $(f(x)-f(x-1))(f(x+1)-f(x))=0$. What can we say about the function?

[EDITED]

Comment: constant valued function , like $f(x) = c$ where $c$ is a constant and it's derivative $= 0$

Comment: @alkabary: Unless it doesn't have to be continuous (e.g., $f(x) = \tan{(\pi x)}$).

Comment: I am wrong , this only works for $f :\mathbb{Z \to Z}$

Comment: @John: That example is not non-decreasing (no matter how you define $f(1/2)$ etc.), e.g. because $f(0)>f(3/4)$.

Comment: Daniel: Where is the problem from?

Comment: I rolled back you last edit. Please do not deface the post by removing all content.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: It is **NOT** only constant functions.  Consider $f(x)=0$ if $x<0$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x\geq 0$.  This function satisfies for any $x$ either $f(x)=f(x+1)$ or $f(x)=f(x-1)$.

Hint: Not every "step" function satisfies your requirement.  For example, the floor function does not satisfy it (because the flat intervals are too short).

Hint: The only functions that do satisfy your constraint are step functions (but not all step functions satisfy it).  This is because if $f(x)$ is constant on $[a,b]$ (on step) and $f(b+\epsilon)>f(b)$ and $f(a-\epsilon)<f(a)$ then $f(a+\epsilon+1)=f(a+\epsilon)$ and $f(b-\epsilon-1)=f(b-\epsilon)$.  In particular $a\epsilon+1\in [a,b]$ and $b-\epsilon-1\in [a, b]$ for arbitrarily small $\epsilon$.

Final Hint (probably): either $(a+b)/2 - 1 \in [a,b]$ or $(a+b)/2+1\in [a,b]$.  That should help get a better bound on the minimum width of the step interval.  Note that $b\geq a+1$ so the distance from $a$ to $(a+b)/2$ is at least $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: For your first example: $f\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)=0$ while $f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=1$, right? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @JohnChessant, that is correct, but $f(-1/2)=f(-1/2-1)$.  This satisfies the requirement.

Comment: Okay; I was misinterpreting the problem. (I thought both $f(x)=f(x+1)$ _and_ $f(x)=f(x-1)$ had to be true.)

Comment: I interpreted the question differently (maybe wrongly). TravisJ interprets the question as it is formulated, though i don't know if this is how Daniel Ciu intended it?

Comment: @DanielChiu, $f(x)$ must be constant on $[a,b]$ since $f(a)=f(b)$ and $f$ is non-decreasing.

Comment: @DanielChiu, it depends on how wide that arbitrary interval is.  Any increasing step function will satisfy your conditions provided that each step has width at least (xxx) where (xxx) is something I'll leave for you to figure out.  Look at my last hint for help with that.

Comment: @DanielChiu, note also that I only consider the case here where one step was a closed interval.  A step could be half-open or open.  If there is something specific you are looking for, you should add that to the question.  Also, I will be happy to provide more than hints once you show what work you have put in (e.g. if you think you have a completed solution and want to check for gaps, I'm happy to check for gaps).